# Access php status information from inside php

Tags: php, fpm

php-fpm provides a status page for those who are interested. It looks like this:

```
curl http://localhost/server-status
pool: default
process manager: dynamic
start time: 11/Dec/2014:17:51:33 -0500
start since: 61383
accepted conn: 4682
listen queue: 0
max listen queue: 0
listen queue len: 0
idle processes: 11
active processes: 1
total processes: 12
max active processes: 2
max children reached: 0
slow requests: 3
```

How do I access this information from php? Please don't tell me to use curl to request the status page from localhost.

Comment: I believe that's actually an apache listener, not PHP.

Comment: hum, ok, so open a socket to port 80, send a "GET /server-status", read from socket ?  Or fopen on /server-status, then read.  Or file_get_contents() You have to read it from URL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797794/apache-server-status-mod-status-output-as-in-json-or-xml-format might give you some help

Comment: @aynber That's a different thing. PHP-FPM does have its own separate built-in status page.

Comment: What's wrong with using a curl request? The whole point of making it available via HTTP is so that you can request it remotely. If having to parse the output is your issue, note that you can append `?json` or `?xml` to the request.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I want to make the information available to a prometheus exporter I want export other metrics too. And using curl from inside a php process to learn something about the process itself would feel wrong.

Comment: Is there anything of use in `$_SERVER`? Or `ini_get_all()`?

Comment: Regarding the 1st sentence: Using curl doesn't prevent you from being able to do that. Regarding the 2nd: You're not learning about the process you're in, you're learning about the process that spawned the process you're in.

Comment: 1) You're right Alex, it's dirty though. 2) The information is in shared memory. So it's available to all the children. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_status.c

Comment: It's one line of code. You're trying to micro-optimize a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `server-status` from FPM is not PHP mechanism. You cannot get it by internal PHP mechanisms.

Your only way to reach this is using some kind of connect mechanism to fpm server itself.

1. You can get it by grabbing info from url with `CURL` or `file_get_contents()` or any other mechanisms that fetches data from url.
2. You can connect local socket with shell exec using parameters like:

(shell code)

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/status \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php-fpm/www.sock
```

3. You can use some kind of variation of socket connecting with parameters. I haven't tried that, but a good place to start is here: https://github.com/wizaplace/php-fpm-status-cli
4. Probably if you get very stubborn you can find another creative way, but either of them are doing it as internal mechanism of PHP-FPM.

Answer (score -1):

In ubuntu I was able to access PHP-FPM status page by this

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/status SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

**Note:** You may get not found error while running above command, like

```
Primary script unknown
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

File not found.
```

If you are getting this error make sure you have uncommented `pm.status_path = /status` in `pool.d/www.conf`.

Absolute path for that config file in ubuntu 17.04 with PHP 7 is `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and line number is 232

After editing conf file restart fpm with `service php7.0-fpm restart`

**GETTING IT VIA PHP SCRIPT**

You can get output of php-fpm status by running above command via php with [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
exec( 'SCRIPT_NAME=/status SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock', $php_fpm_status );

// Above statement will assign an array to $php_fpm_status filled with every line of output from the command, make it as whole string

$php_fpm_status = implode(PHP_EOL, $php_fpm_status);

// You can try printing php-fpm status

echo $php_fpm_status;
```

Comment: I'm looking for the fpm status, not apache status.